# MEF - Help understanding what's going on with the container and composition

Tags: c#, .net, mef

## Issue

I'm implementing plugins with MEF for a WinForms application and I'm noticing some behavior with composition that I don't understand.

Just to get it out of the way, I'm using MEF with .NET 4.

As sort of a tl;dr, here is what I'm not clear on in regards to containers and composition:

1. If I construct a container inside of a class which is, itself, an exported part and then call `ComposeParts(this)` is the existing instance of that class added to the container or is another instance created?
2. When I use the `GetExportedValue<T>()` method, should the part returned already be composed (or had its imports filled) or do I need to explicitly compose the part?

Read on for more details about each question...

## Background

Regarding the first question, I have a main application form which has a panel that will host "normal" application usercontrols as well as usercontrols from plugins.  This main application form implements an interface called `IHostingForm` which allows it to expose some of its own functionality to plugins.  This main application form exports itself through the `IHostingForm` interface and has an import which needs to be filled.  Here's a code snippet:

```
[Export(typeof(IHostingForm))]
public partial class frmMain : RibbonForm, IHostingForm
{
    //public/private form methods here...
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    //An import that needs to be filled.
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IAddInController, IAddInControllerMetadata>> AddInControllers;

    public frmMain()
    {
        //Init code here omitted to save space...

        //Setup the container
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        //Temporary location while testing...
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Application.StartupPath));

        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        try
        {
            //Is the current instance of the class (this) added to the
            //container or does the container construct its own instance?
            _container.ComposeParts(this);
        }
        catch (CompositionException ex)
        {
            //Error catching code omitted...
        }
    }

    //IHostingForm implementation
    public void AddTabToTabBar(string tabText)
    {
        RibbonTab rt = new RibbonTab(tabText);
        //Some more init code here which I'm leaving out to save space...
        this.ribbonBar1.CommandTabs.Add(rt);
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Notice in the snippet above how it is exporting itself but it also calls `ComposeParts(this)` in the constructor?  Does this create a separate instance of the form or is `ComposeParts(this)` smart enough to know to use the already existing instance and just add it to the container?

This leads to my second question.  Since I wasn't sure if the method of composition that I was using above was correct or not, I tried creating the container in the application's Program class and I found another behavior that I don't understand.  I moved the container initialization code out of the form's class and into Program like this:

```
static class Program
{
    internal static CompositionContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //Setup the container
        var catalog = New AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Application.StartupPath));

        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        IHostingForm frm = _container.GetExportedValue<IHostingForm>();
        //If I don't call this, the form's imports don't get satisfied
        _container.CompostParts(frm);
        Application.Run((Form)frm);
    }
}
```

Based on the documentation on MSDN and also [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053720), I was under the impression that the `GetExportedValue<T>()` method would instantiate the export of the given type and also compose it (or satisfy its dependencies?) because it was coming out of the container.  But through testing, it seems that after getting the part from the container I have to explicitly tell the container to compose the part in order to get its imports filled. This seems to contradict with what I've read so far.

I wasn't sure if this was multiple questions or not.  If they need to be split up, let me know and I'll be happy to edit this question and create another one.  But, to me, they seem related in that they're both dealing with my lack of understanding of what is going on with the container and composition.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice in the snippet above how it is exporting itself but it also calls ComposeParts(this) in the constructor? Does this create a separate instance of the form or is ComposeParts(this) smart enough to know to use the already existing instance and just add it to the container?

It's 'smart enough' as in, it will do what it's told. `ComposeParts(this)` will first look at which `Import`s need to be satisfied for `this`. It will then try to find the type/types with a matching `Export` and call their parameterless constructor, after an instance has been created it will look at that type's `Import`s and start all over again.

Now if at some point it encounters an `Import` directive that asks for a type that was already created, it will feed the already existing instance into that `Import` directive - instead of creating a second instance.

You can easily verify this by adding a parameterless constructor to a few types and put a breakpoint in there.

As for your second question, I would suggest asking a seperate question - but as far as I know, `ComposeParts` will find or instantiate previously unused/unknown parts *and* advertise the `Export` attribute of the type/object it was called from - in your case `[Export(typeof(IHostingForm))]`. On the other hand `GetExportedValue` will only search the already existing parts and *not* instantiate new parts - which means if an `Import` asks for part X but no such part was previously created by `ComposeParts` or `SatisfyImports` - the property/field behind that `Import` will stay unsatisfied/`null`.